# Insertar código php o html o js en algunas páginas

Tags: php, javascript, html, prestashop

Quiero añadir código en mi página web en prestashop pero solo quiero que se muestre en algunos productos. Si lo añado en su código de la web me lo va a mostrar en todos y solo quiero en algunos que yo pueda elegir.

¿Hay alguna forma de limitar el código por algún enlace o algo así?

Comment: Buenas por favor revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema? ¿Has leído la documentación de Prestashop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Muchas gracias por las respuesta, ya he podido hacer un apaño he reutilizado los "fabricantes" añadiendo al código una linea que muestre lo que deseaba unido a un fabricante creado, entonce eligiendo el fabricante ese en los productos deseados pues ya me lo muestra, es algo fuarro pero funciona bien.

Perdonen las molestias y gracias,

Answer (score 1):

Un modo (sucio) seria directamente en el tpl:

```
{if $product.id_product==1}

 hacer algo

{elseif $product.id_product==2}

hacer otra cosa
{/if}
```

Si no hazte un metodo estatico en la clase product y llamalo, o crea un modulo y ejecuta el hook en el tpl.